# How to make text labels stick next to an image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image in a Bootstrap's modal that has text-labels surrounding it. Therefore the position of the text is crucial when I shrink the browser (it has to be responsively accurate)

I could easily do this with an image where the text is also in the png like this but I don't like it.
[image: What I want to do]

What I tried:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="container-fluid">
<img class="" src="img/panel/cutaway-drawing.png">
  <span class="a">Open frame technology</span>
  <span class="b">Roxul rock wool</span>
  <span class="c">Camira fabric</span>
  <span class="d">Damped membrane technology</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
}
.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}
.c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 70%;
}
.d {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 70%;
}
```

This should work fine except I have no idea why the absolute positions of `.a .b .c .d` takes `.modal-body` as the parent instead of `.container-fluid`.

Comment: What's the CSS for `.modal-body` and `.container-fluid`?

Comment: add position relative to .container-fluid no?

Comment: These 2 classes are default in bootstrap. But one moment I'll add them in in question.

Comment: @DavidChase That solved it. Thanks I must be too tired to not see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add position:relative to .container-fluid